How do I execute get_query_results after get_query_execution has finished?
I have my code here in my lambda:
import json
import boto3
import time

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('athena')
    
    #execute query to retrieve athena metadata
    queryStart = client.start_query_execution(
        QueryString = """SELECT *FROM information_schema.columns
                         WHERE table_catalog = 'table-catalog-name'
                         AND table_schema = 'schema'
                         ORDER BY table_name, column_name""",
        QueryExecutionContext = {
            'Database': 'database'
            },
        ResultConfiguration = {
            'OutputLocation': 's3://bucket-name/'
            }
        )

    #results
    queryId = queryStart['QueryExecutionId']
    time.sleep(15)
    
    results = client.get_query_execution(QueryExecutionId = queryId)
    results = client.get_query_results(QueryExecutionId = queryId)
    for row in results['ResultSet']['Rows']:
        print(row)

Technically, it works even though it throws this error:
"errorMessage": "An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the GetQueryResults operation: Query has not yet finished. Current state: RUNNING"

I checked the S3 bucket and my CSV file was outputted there with all the data from the Athena query. I am not sure why I am getting this error. I know I need to check and see if
results = client.get_query_execution(QueryExecutionId = queryId) finished before it checks if:
results = client.get_query_results(QueryExecutionId = queryId) has ran? But it works anyway, I don't know how to get rid of the error.

What's the point of calling get_query_execution() if you are just throwing away the response it returns? Why not use that response to check if the execution is finished?

From get_query_execution - Boto3 documentation:

Returns information about a single execution of a query.

{
    'QueryExecution': {
        'Status': {
            'State': 'QUEUED'|'RUNNING'|'SUCCEEDED'|'FAILED'|'CANCELLED',
            ...
}

Your program should keep calling get_query_execution() while State in ['QUEUED', 'RUNNING'].
Then, you can check whether it succeeded/failed/was cancelled. If the state is SUCCEEDED, you can then call get_query_results().
For example:
    queryId = queryStart['QueryExecutionId']
    
    while True:
      time.sleep(5)
    
      query_execution = client.get_query_execution(QueryExecutionId = queryId)

      state = query_execution['QueryExecution']['Status']['State']

      if state == 'SUCCEEDED':
        query_results = client.get_query_results(QueryExecutionId = queryId)
        break;
      elif state in ['FAILED', 'CANCELLED']:
        raise Exception(f'Query {state}')


